# How to abstract away an implementation that requires runtime data during its construction?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have some trouble with dependency injection. Assume we have the following code:

**[Snippet 1]**

```cs
public class FooBar 
{ 
  public FooBar (){}

  public void DoSomething(string param1, int param2)
  {
    var reader = new Reader(param1, param2)
    parser.Read();
  }  
}
```

I don' t want anymore the class `FooBar` to use the `new` operator. I will have two kinds of parsers `ExcelParser` and `XmlParser`. They both implement an interface `IParser`. Then depending on the configuration I will add one Parser or another, i.e., in `Program.cs` I will have something like

```cs
if (Environment == something) {
  services.AddSingleton<IParser,ExcelParser>();
} else {
  serrvices.AddSingleton<IParser,XmlParser();
}
```

The code will be something like this

My question is: In snippet 1, to instantiate the Paser we passed `param1` and `param2`. In snippet 2, How will the DI container get those parameters to create an instance? Something is missing in my understanding of DI.

Comment: If you want to instantiate a`FooBar` object without using `new`, you'll have to register FooBar with the DI container, and I don't see anywhere in your code where you do that.  Explaining the rest of how this works is probably beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow question, but the broad brush strokes are:

Comment: 1.  Your FooBar constructor needs to take interfaces as parameters, not concrete types.

Comment: 2.  You need to register your types with the DI container, including `Type1` and `Type2`, so that the DI container knows how to instantiate objects of those types to satisfy FooBar's constructor.

Comment: @RobertHarvey "take interfaces as parameters, not concrete types" - I yet to see DI container that does not support concrete types... Are you sure that is exactly what you wanted to say?

Comment: 3.  Because you will be providing interfaces as your constructor parameters (and not concrete types), your registrations will have to give enough information to the DI container so that it can match concrete types with interfaces.  IType1 -> Type1, for example.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Without interfaces as parameters, there's no way to substitute a different, conforming type (like a mock object, for instance).  You can do it without interfaces, but it will greatly diminish the value of DI; you might as well just use `new` in that case.

Comment: And if you are using concrete types as parameters, you can get most of the benefits of DI by creating an aggregate root, and putting all of your instantiations for your object graph there.  The whole point of DI is to decouple your classes from concrete dependencies; that's what the interfaces are for.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sorry. Neglect the `Type1` and `Type2` they are not relevant to the question here

Comment: @RobertHarvey fair simplification... but I'm not sure if that would help OP to understand what *a generic DI container* normally would support and what would be nice-to-have. I.e. you know that mocking a class is not harder that mocking an interface (as long as necessary methods are virtual) as well as not every type needs to be mocked to be able to test the code (i.e. "configuration"/DTO don't need to be mocked)...

Comment: @RobertHarvey The question is really about, if we inject an `IParser`. The DI will create an instance of the needed Parser. However, to create an instance of parser, there are two parameters that are needed, namely `param1` and `param2`. How the DI will get those parameters?

Comment: The same way it gets any other parameter, by instantiating them.  Just as you would with the `new` keyword.  The DI container will recursively work through all of your dependencies in your constructor until all of them are instantiated.

Comment: You need to think about what your actual goal is.  It's not "eliminate the `new` keyword;" that's just a technique in pursuit of a goal.  What is your *actual* goal?  Is it decoupling?  Simplification?  Or is is slavishly following someone else's "rule" without a rationale?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am trying to understand the idea, not following anyone's rules. I am not sure I understand what do mean. Previously, in snippet 1, `param1` and `param2` are passed in because they are coming from the `DoSomething` method. But in snippet 2, if we remove the line `new Parser(param1,param2)` .... How the DI will find those parameters ?

Comment: Typically a DI container uses [*reflection*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) to examine the parameters in each constructor.  That's how it knows what to instantiate and how to instantiate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `IParser` interface to:

```cs
public interface IParser
{
    void Execute(string param1, string param2);
}
```

This way, `FooBar` can pass on the parameters without having to instantiate the parser:

```cs
public class FooBar 
{ 
  private readonly IParser _parser;
  
  public FooBar(IParser parser)
  {
      _parser = parser;
  }

  public void DoSomething(string param1, int param2)
  {
      _parser.Execute(param1, param2);
  } 
}
```

More details on why and how can be found in this article: [Dependency Injection Code Smell: Injecting runtime data into components](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/).

Comment: That gets you halfway there.  To satisfy the OP's goal of "no `new` keyword," you have to do a bit more than this.

Comment: @RobertHarvey what's missing then?

Comment: A mechanism for instantiating objects without the use of the `new` keyword.  Adding interfaces just adds a layer of indirection; you still need the objects that implement those interfaces.

Comment: @RobertHarvey but having a class `Parser` that implements `IParser` and with an empty constructor will be sufficient, right?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: In the question, OP mentioned code like `services.AddSingleton<IParser,ExcelParser>()`. My assumption is that OP already has implementations for `IParser` (namely `ExcelParser` and `XmlParser`) and is using a DI Container that allows composing object graphs and the DI Container will create the implementations on OP's behalf. As a matter of fact, the signature of the `services.AddSingleton` call matches a commonly used DI Container in the .NET space. If you think my assumptions are wrong or if I'm still missing something, please let me know.